# How can I set the location of the redirect returned from the POST to /signin-oidc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have an application hosted at `domain.tld/ui` using OpenIdConnect.

I believe I have configured the request back from the authority to return correctly to the signin-oidc URL. Here:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://domain.tld/ui/signin-oidc";
    }
}
```

That creates a POST request to `https://domain.tld/ui/signin-oidc` it responds with `302 Found` with a location of `https://domain.tld/log-in`. In my case I believe this needs to be `https://domain.tld/ui/log-in`. How can I change this?

I have tried setting `options.CallbackPath = "/ui"` in:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.CallbackPath = "/ui";
}
```

But, when I do that I get a 500 from the POST to `https://domain.tld/ui/signin-oidc`. With an exception of `InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.`

I believe if I can configure the `location` header on the `302 Found` response to include the `/ui/` piece of the URI my application will work. If I navigate to `https://domain.tld/ui` after being redirectred to `https://domain.tld/log-in` my application works as expected.

Here is my `Configure` method as requested:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsEnvironment("dev") || env.IsEnvironment("qa"))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            return next();
        });

        app.UseForwardedHeaders();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (!Config.Settings.LoggingConfig.CaptureTelemetry)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
        }

        app.UseExceptionMiddleware();

        app.UseClaimMiddleware();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // serve files in wwwroot
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                if (!env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    // add cache control header to .js files in dist/ not in dist/maps
                    var javascriptRegex = new Regex(@".*dist\/(?!maps).*\.js(\?v=.*)?");

                    if (javascriptRegex.IsMatch(ctx.Context.Request.Path.ToString()))
                    {
                        const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10;
                        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public,max-age={durationInSeconds}");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.ApplicationBuilder.UseResponseCaching();

            spa.ApplicationBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                            new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                            {
                                NoCache = true
                            };
                    context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
                        new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

                    await next();
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the `Startup.Configure` method? In ASP.NET Core, the order you call `app.UseXXX` matters greatly

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've added the Configure method.

Comment: @Anthony 2 years later, I ran into same problem as yours. You managed to fix it? Setting options.CallbackPath did not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same issue:

• The location in the HTTP Response header of the 302 Redirect is just "/", instead of "/X/Y".

• After navigating to the incorrect Redirect URL, if I manually browse to "/X/Y" from the browser, the user is already considered to logged in, and proceeds to load the web page.

This issue only happens if I host the Webapp and IdentityServer inside Kubernetes with Nginx-Ingress as reverse proxy.

My workaround is to set the context.Request.PathBase = "/x/y" inside an app.use() middleware of the webapp.
I am not sure if this is a safe workaround as it forces all Request.PathBase to "/x/y".

I noticed that if I hosted the application inside IIS, and calls builder.WebHost.UseIISIntegration(), all context.Request.PathBase are automatically set, when I try to inspect the context.Request.PathBase values from a middleware. That's where I got the idea for the workaround.